# Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint + PIA

Tags: ms-office, office-interop, office-pia

I have used Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint in my desktop application.

I want to run its EXE on another machine. Does that machine required MS office to be installed or simply by installing PIA (Primary Interop Assembly) distributable on that machine will do the work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the associated office product installed on the destination machine. This is how microsoft makes moneys.

The Interops only invoke functionality from within the Office applications.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/b4026f0b-c3a3-4b80-81df-5175e866ae8f